# How to set virtual `T` register programmatically in IDA Python?

Tags: ida, idapython

It is trivial to do it with `Alt+G` command from GUI.

However, when I set multiple breakpoints programmatically, IDA doesn't recognize them as "thumb" mode ones and sets `T` value at breakpoint address to `0`. When IDA tries to use ARM mode instead of Thumb, it is guaranteed to crash.

Setting `T` value 50 times manually is supposed to be too slow.

So, I try to set `T = 1` programmatically.

However, I have no idea how to do that.

I tried this:

```
idaapi.set_sreg_at_next_code(function_pointer, function_pointer + 2, idaapi.str2reg("T"), 1)
```

And this:

```
idaapi.set_default_sreg_value(idaapi.getseg(function_pointer), idaapi.str2reg("T"), 1)
```

IDA simply ignores both calls, no error occurs, but `T` value doesn't change.

Does anyone know how to change virtual `T` segment register value with IDAPython in ARM mode?

Answer (score 2):

I found solution myself. Correct code follows:

```
idaapi.split_sreg_range(instruction_pointer, idaapi.str2reg("T"), required_t_value, idaapi.SR_user)
```

where `instruction_pointer` is instruction address which mode you want to change, and `required_t_value` is new mode (`1` for Thumb, `0` for ARM), and